# Remove schema from Entity Framework 6.X migration against Oracle database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When EF code migration is generated it contains schema / user string, such as:

```
CreateTable(
    "MYSCHEMA.QA_CALCQUEUE",
    c => new
        {
            CALCREQID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 19, scale: 0, identity: true),
            ACTIONCODE = c.String(maxLength: 32),
            ACTIONTEXT = c.String(maxLength: 2048),
            CALCQAMEASID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
            QAMEASID = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
            TIMESTAMP = c.DateTime()
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.CALCREQID)
    .ForeignKey("MYSCHEMA.QA_MEAS", t => t.QAMEASID)
    .ForeignKey("MYSCHEMA.QA_MEAS", t => t.CALCQAMEASID)
```

Where **MYSCHEMA** is the schema name.
When I **omit** it by using below code in **DbContext**:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(string.Empty);
}
```

The generated **migration will not contain the schema**, **but it will fail** during application of the migration.
Is there some way how to make migrations without the schema name?
I can only think of replacing the **MYSCHEMA** with a string variable, but ultimate solution would not require that after migration is generated.